# Attaching a callback to html generated by JSF - Primefaces 

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, callback, primefaces

I've got a Primefaces command button that I need to add a callback to in jQuery on document.ready.  Basically what I've been trying to do is get a reference to the existing function and then call it in a new function that I wrote:

```
var existingFunction = jQuery("[id~='submit']").live("click");
jQuery("[id~='submit']").live("click", function(){
    existingFunction();
    alert('test');
    updateControlPanel(buildControlPanelUrl(getUrlVars()));
});
```

It seems simple enough to me but for some reason this will not work.  When I load the page and click the submit button it doesn't even reach the alert.

I've checked the error console and found that it's throwing the following errors:

```
((f.event.special[s.origType] || {}).handle || s.handler).apply is not a function
```

There is existing jQuery functions on the page that I did not write but I'd like to make sure this error is not related to the way I'm approaching this.

I'm using tomcat 6 with an older version of JQuery (1.3 or 1.4 ).

Thanks and let me know if you guys need any more info.

**Edit**

I've put up an example of what I'm trying to do on JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/anSXH/2/

Here is some further clarification:
I've built the button as a project in JSF 2.0 (MyFaces) using the latest Primefaces component library. I've then taken that button and embedded it into an existing web page.  The button submits the form and then calls a JavaScript function to show the result on the page after an ajax request is complete.  This all works when I embed the button onto the page but I now need to update something on the client side after the button calls the function.  That's why I'm looking at adding a callback to the existing onclick function.

As a side note, because I'm using Primefaces I can attach a JavaScript function to run after the ajax request is complete.  My plan B is to try and access this function and somehow override it.

**Edit part 2**
Here is the generated control from primefaces:

```
<button 
 id="topsaveform:submittop"
 name="topsaveform:submittop"
 class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only"
 onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({source:'topsaveform:submittop',process:'topsaveform OEIMeasurementsTable',update:'errorMessages submittedPopup',onstart:function(cfg){jQuery('#loadingBar').show('fast');;},oncomplete:function(xhr,status,args){postSubmit();;}});return false;" 
 type="submit">
   <span class="ui-button-text">Save</span>
</button>
```

Comment: Please put you sample code on jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com so we could see live code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was trying to do this with a primefaces button.  When I switched to a standard JSF button I was able to affix the function to it no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try making the original function `die` ([ref](http://api.jquery.com/die/))?

```
jQuery("[id~='submit']").die("click");
jQuery("[id~='submit']").live("click", function(){
    alert('test');
    updateControlPanel(buildControlPanelUrl(getUrlVars()));
});
```

Comment: I tried using die but it didn't seem to make any difference.  I'm not attaching the onclick event on the client side though so I'm not sure if this is going to help.  I'm actually already doing this with some dropdowns on the page and it works for them so I'm not sure what the issue is here.